# Javascript doesn't without using onload event

Tags: javascript

The code that i am working on is this-

```
var winW;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
}
if (winW = 1265) {
function setPosition()
{
document.getElementById("wblogo").style.left="1050px";
}
}
```

The code works perfectly when i use it with the `onload` event in the `body` tag.

But i want to use this when the page is being loaded. So i used the following code-

```
var winW;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
}
if (winW = 1265) {
document.getElementById("wblogo").style.left="1050px";
}
```

But this code doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that when you removed the `onload`, you left your script in the `head` section of the document. The elements you're trying to work with (`document.body`, your `wblogo` element) *don't exist yet*, so the code can't interact with them. When you were using `onload`, your code wasn't being run right away, but instead **very** late in the page load cycle after all images and such were loaded, and so the elements did exist.

Instead, put your code in a `script` tag at the **end** of your document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. That way, the elements you're trying to work with will exist.

More:

- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google on when DOM elements are available](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)